# How to perform arithmetic operation recorded in a field in a select with Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table lake that :

---

**TABLE A** 

id | arithmetic     | column2 
1  |{id1}/{id2}     |  bla bla 
2  |{id3}+{id5}*1000| other bla bla 
3  | ...

**another table  - TABLE B**

id | values | 
1  | 4      |
2  | 7      |
3  | 0,25   | 
...

---

I wanna take a QUERY  that execute the arithmetic operator in TABLE A using values of TABLE B .

Considering I already have managed to make the replacement of the codes by the figures in table B , they are as string is read as a string and not as a number, if I use a CONVERT ( arithmetic , unsigned integer) , it does not execute the expression but yes transforms the numbers encontraods to the first mathematical operator . 
I trying to use convert(@arithmetic, unsigned integer), but not sucessfull.

Like a example in a simple select :

Select '5+2', results '5+2';

but if I use select 5+2 , results 7.

therefore if I use select convert ( '5+2', unsigned integer); , results 5 ( read until the first character not mathematical).

In short words : read and execute a math expression wrote inside a field?

Comment: Oh interesting but impractical I think you would need to check for different symbols for each mathematical operation,separate the variables,then build the expression and concate-execute it.You would build esentially a math parser.

Comment: My problem is the context , I need list management indicators made with different mathematical formulas with n factors and n variations

Comment: I think i remember on this site a function which parsed simple math operations but I doubt what you want is possible only in mysql.

Comment: This should be done in your application, or store the precalculated values..

Comment: Don't do it. If there is the place for is, then not in DB query, but in application. But - don't do it there as well. Just don't do it, reconsider your structure

Comment: I doubt but also talked to the DBA and he made notes about performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General notes**

First thing first, make sure that you're not in the middle of [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) with your architecture. DBMS should not handle such logic solution in general, as the logic is not part of data, it should be part of application. However, even in application, you should avoid run-time evaluation as it in most cases not safe and unpredictable (thus, source from any kind of problems).

**Solution with DBMS**

While I would not recommend to go this way - with evaluation of expression on run-time, it is still possible with [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), like:

```
SET @expr:=(
  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT ', arithmetic, ' AS expr') SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ') AS expr 
  FROM tableA
);

PREPARE execSelect FROM @expr;

EXECUTE execSelect;
```

Working fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fff7d/7). I may even imagine values substitution, but I would not recommend to go this way. If you really need this, then, most probably, something is wrong with architecture breakdown, since your data within SQL needs to hold some logic - and that's the goal for your application, not for your database.